# Laravel Eloquent, set has many relation though 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a user that can has multiple projects.

So I'd like to define a relation in the `User` model

```
public function projects() {

  return //some code here

}
```

The problem is that to reach the User's project, I need to go though 2 different tables. So for this case is not possible to use `hasManyThough` or just `hasMany`.

How do I set up a one to many relation that goes though 2 different tables, instead of just one (ie. a pivot table)?

Comment: can you put the database schema to make it more clear?

Comment: documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: *one to many relation that goes though 2 different tables* is a bit unclear, no, its totally unclear.. can specify.. like is it A (1) --- (n) B (1) --- (n) C or.. something else? ever read [`HasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_hasManyThrough)?

Answer (score 0):

just use eloquent in your model.. just define hasmany/belongsto or etc for you each model

sample :

```
$user->table_b->table_c->project()... this just sample.. you can use 'with'


class User extends Model
{
    protected appends = ['template'];

    public function table_b() {
        return $this->hasMany(TableB::class);
    }
}

class TableB extends Model
{
    public function table_c() {
        return $this->hasMany(TableC::class);
    }
}

class TableC extends Model
{
    public function project() {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{

}
```